# Open and Close Circuit automatically (Automate Push Button)

Tags: timer, button

I have a simple circuit board with a push button on it. I just want to automate the pressing action every 0.2 sec or so. The push button has two terminals underneath and I understand that I should connect both terminals in order to close the circuit and simulate the pressing action.

Having this in mind, how can I automate this action every 0.2 sec or so? I guess that I should use a "Timer Relay Delay" like this: [DC 6V~30V Multifunction Trigger Delay Time Module Switch Control Relay Cycle Timer Digit LED Display Micro USB 5V](https://www.amazon.ca/6V-30V-Multifunction-Trigger-Control-Display/dp/B07CYMTM5R/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?s=kitchen&ie=UTF8&qid=1539136244&sr=1-1-spons&keywords=timer%20relay%20cycle&psc=1)

However, I don't know where I should connect both terminals of the push button.

Can anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 1):

A good start for this sort of project would be to use an Arduino.

They are micro-controller made easy for beginner to use, with a lot of community and code example available.

Learning Arduino will be a bit more difficult than using a device as you suggested, but it will open a bunch of new doors into different projects you would like to make on the future.

You can program the Arduino to give you the 0.2 sec signal to a pin, and then you can use a relay to replace the push button.

There is probably better than the relay, but we would need a little bit more what this button action controls.